# Boost asio for multiple asynchronous network client operations

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

I want to use boost::asio (or asio stand alone) to query multiple network devices once a minute for data via asynchronous sockets. For a test I have already implemented a Client class and a console program that does that for one device (without repetition).
Something like this:

```
class MyClient
{
public:
    MyClient(asio::io_service& io_service);

    void GetData(CompletionHandler completionHandler);
};
```

The MyClient::GetData class uses several asynchronous operations internally where the completion of each operation triggers the next until the data are available:

- Connect
- Read header
- Read data
- Disconnect

The console program that uses this class works like this:

```
int main(...)
{
    asio::io_service io_service_;

    MyClient c(io_service_, ...);
    ...
    c.GetData([](std::error_code ec, const FloatVector& values){
        //do something with values
    });

    io_service_.run();
    ...
}
```

Now I want to use the MyClient class in a GUI program for connecting to >10 devices once a minute but I'm stuck on the overall design.

First I created a thread pool where each thread executes io_service::run() of a single io_service instance.

Now whenever my program wants to read data from the devices it would have a loop over all devices and would have to create an instance of MyClient for each and call the GetData() method.

How does that work together with the io_service now that io_service::run() is executed in the threads of a pool? Can I simply call MyClient::GetData() in the GUI thread because it uses asynchronous operations internally or do I have to call something like io_service::post() ?

**Update:**
My code and console demo follows roughly this example:
www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp

But in a GUI program I don't want to run io_service.run() in the GUI thread. Now assume I have at least one extra thread that executes io_service.run() and a user presses a button that should start the device reading. The final completion handler should store the data in a database and update a graphical display to the user.

Maybe the button handler can simply instantiate MyClient and call GetData() on it and everything works as it should since MyClient knows the io_service and uses it f.e. in async_connect etc.

Does it work like this or am I mistaken here?

Note: at this point my question is not how to handle the data in the completion handler! It is how to correctly get the data in a multithreaded GUI program.

Comment: What exactly can the user do from the GUI?  Is the GUI simply displaying the results from those devices?  Think about a UI thread and another single thread talking to all those devices that executes io_service::run().  The asio thread would typically be posting a message to the GUI thread once it has the latest data and then the GUI thread processes that event and displays the result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough outline of what you need to do:

- First note that io_service.run() will return immediately if it has no work to do.  So depending on your workflow you may need to defer calling it until you actually have the first asynchronous connect queued up.  If you look at the example client you'll see that first the client is instantiated which queues up the first operation (an asynchronous resolve in this case) and then io_service.run() is called.
- So assuming you are starting on a button press what you need to do at this point is schedule the connect or resolve and then spin up a new thread and call io_service.run() from that thread.
- Once the chain of asynchronous operations completes and you have your data your handler will be called in the context of the new thread you've spun up.  This means you have to post a message back to your UI (since typically UI work can only be done on the main thread).  E.g. your lambda in your example needs to do some sort of UI post message operation (details depend on which OS/GUI we're talking about here).
- Then your GUI thread will pick up that message and update whatever UI state you want updated (e.g. display the result)

Comment: Thanks, that answers most of my question. Only this thing: wouldn't it make sense to have a threadpool with as much threads as processors (remember that I have to connect to at least 10 devices at the same time)? And if so, wouldn't I create the threadpool in advance? I read about something like creating a "dummy" work item to prevent io_service.run() from immediately returning.

Comment: @NicolasR the thread pool makes sense if you have enough work to keep a single core 100% busy.  It doesn't sound like that would be a problem for you so one thread is probably enough.  Since the real work is done asynchronously there should be no problem connecting to 10 or even thousands of devices...

Comment: Great! That's all I needed.

Comment: @GuySirton in the second point, you mentioned , schedule connect and resolve , then fire another thread for io_service.run(). But as far as i know, async operations should be queued on the same thread on which io_service.run() is called.. isint it?

Comment: @ashishsony Not necessarily.  There can be multiple threads all calling io_service.run().  Typically operations are queued as a result of a callback which happens on some thread that has called io_service.run() but that doesn't have to be the case, e.g.. the very first async operation you queue up.

Answer (score 1):

Check this example www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp . That should help.

If you see if handle_resolve is successful, it calls async_connect which will result in handle_connect to be fired. If handle_connect was called with no error, it writes some data to the connection (async_write) which in turn call async_read_until (on no error) which will fire handle_read_status_line, which may fire handle_read_headers, which may fire handle_read_content.
If you see there is no explicit disconnect as the destructor will do this internally.

Comment: Yes, that is more or less what I have now: a client class and io_service::run() in  the same thread in a console program. How to advance that to a GUI program? I will try to update my question to make it more clear.